# How do I use the TEXT function for special notation of HEX value?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formatting

I need to first convert a DEC into HEX and then apply a special display mask to the final cell display. With the formula below I can get this done OK for all HEX values that are strictly numbers, but whenever letters are included only the original HEX value gets displayed.

Decimal number is located in cell `A1`

Current formula is `=TEXT(DEC2HEX(A1),"0000\.0000\.0000\.0000)`

Working example:
If `A1 = 8414472`
Then `HEX = 806508`
Then formatted result correctly shows: `0000.0000.0080.6508`

Where it breaks:
If `A1 = 3672686`
Then `HEX = 380A6E`
The Formatted result shows original/unformatted HEX value: `380A5E`
Instead of the desired: `0000.0000.0038.0A5E`

Example of more inputs and results:
[Screenshot of more examples](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJa5T.png)

How can I construct the `=TEXT(value,[format_text])` formula to work on alphanumeric input as well as numeric only?'

Comment: The `TEXT` function won't format Hex numbers. You can create the substrings and then join them. Or you could create a VBA function.

Comment: Just a warning about DEC2HEX().  Your decimal values can *easily* overflow the DEC2HEX function.  Hex values are stored in 40 bits in Excel and thus the function is limited to 2^39-1 as the maximum value, or 549,755,813,887.  Your 4x fields of 4 hex digits spans 64 bits.  Thus your first two terms must *always* be .0000.

Comment: Thanks  @maxR , yeah, fortunately this should not become an issue. The decimals that need to be converted and forced into this rather odd formatting will only be person IDs of an organization, so they likely will never grow this high :)

Answer (score 1):

If you have the `TEXTJOIN` function in your version of Excel, you can use the following formula:

*edited to simplify formula*

```
=TEXTJOIN(".",,MID("000000" &DEC2HEX(B1,10),{1,5,9,13},4))
```

If your Hex number is out of range of the `DEC2HEX` function, the formula will return an error.

The largest number returnable by this formula =>`0000.007F.FFFF.FFFF`

Use the Formula Evaluate tool to see how this works, if it is not clear to you.

*If you do not have the `TEXTJOIN` function, you can concatenate each portion of the array formed by the `MID` function separately.*

Comment: Thanks Ron, I'll give this a try later today!

Comment: @MaxWinkler Further to Ron's answer...  what the non-TEXTJOIN, non-array version would look like is: `="0000.00" & MID( DEC2HEX(B1,10),1,2) & "." & MID( DEC2HEX(B1,10),3,4) & "." & MID( DEC2HEX(B1,10),7,4)`  If you wanted to be insanely elegant you could create a long formula (I did it) that would handle integers larger than the DEC2HEX limitation using a series of embedded divisions and MOD() functions.  But Excel only has 15 significant digits, so that approach would only let you hire another quadrillion employees or so.  Should be on the next version of excel by the time you get there.

Comment: Thanks @MaxR , this worked as well :-) Glad to have two options now !